# Classification of categories for e-commerce project

Tags: php, api, e-commerce, categories

I searched it in google but could not find any result. Is there any resource to use it for creating categories in shopping project.
For example: I want to create a category of "Computer". There should be many fields displayed below:
Model, resolution, ram, hdd and etc.
Now the question is:
Where I can to find the API that introduces all of these fields generally.

Answer (score 0):

Javid i think you can't do this :D